# PHP artisan use domain without port number

Tags: php, url, laravel-artisan, hosts

When I serve my laravel project with `php artisan serve --host=yum-yums.local`, I can access the site via `http://yum-yums.local:8000`

My host file has `127.0.0.1         yum-yums.local`

How can I access the site with just `yum-yums.local` please, with no port number appended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

80 port is the default port number of http so you have to use this command to omit the port number:

```
sudo php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=80
```